# Assign button missing from material tab

Tags: materials, interface

Can somebody tell me where the "assign" button, for assigning a material has gone?

[image: Material Preview with assign]

Here is where it should be, but it has gone away:

[image: Assign missing]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

You need to be in *Edit Mode*. That way you can select the vertices to assign to. Otherwise Blender has to use the mesh as one whole surface when applying new materials.

[image: Material Assign Example]

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked :) If this answer helped please accept it by clicking the little checkmark, it really helps my standings on the site.